# Jquery dialog close by clicking link

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm new to use Jquery ui.
I'd like to create a modal dialog box and close it only when I click on the link or image within the modal box.

I found the way to hide close button,but I don't know how set popup close on click or add image with link inside the box.

Can someone provide me full code to obtain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation ( http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#methods ) you can see there is a close function.  When creating the dialog you can attach a click event to any arbitrary element (a new close link/image/button/anything) that calls the close function on that dialog object:

```
var my_dialog = $('#my_div').dialog({});//options, etc

$('#my_div .my_close_link').click(function () {
  my_dialog.close();
});
```

Comment: This isn't free-rent-a-coder. You'd lay out your dialog however you want and add the image/link that closes it whenever your design requires it.  You attach the click event to that arbitrary element.

Comment: Sorry,but is the first time I use jquery and I'm new to javascript.If someone can help me I would be grateful.